# How to create a Matrix that is start from right in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a Matrix in R that is start from right

For example, I want to create a Matrix looks like below:

```
5 4 3 2 1
6 7 8 9 10
10 9 8 7 6
5 4 3 2 1
```

When I input,

```
x = matrix(1:10, nrow=2, ncol=5, byrow = FALSE)
y = matrix(10:1, nrow=2, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE)
M = rbind(x,y)
```

M will become

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
[3,]   10    9    8    7    6
[4,]    5    4    3    2    1
```

So, is there any method to start the counting from right?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

How's this

```
matrix(c(5:1, 6:10, 10:6, 5:1), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are almost there. You should use `byrow = TRUE` for `x` and apply `rev` over the first row of `M`, e.g.,

```
x = matrix(1:10, nrow=2, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE)
y = matrix(10:1, nrow=2, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE)
M = rbind(x,y)

M[1,] <- rev(M[1,])
```

such that

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    4    3    2    1
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
[3,]   10    9    8    7    6
[4,]    5    4    3    2    1
```